# How to build elegant functionality in Android

Tags: android

In recent changes many apps launched a new way of displaying information in android app, like in Hotel Tonight Android App, when user do tap on any of the hotel from the listing and then in another screen when user swipe from bottom to top (it contains everything about that hotel, like: Name, Map, Forecast, Why We Like It, Amenities, Photos etc.) what called it? how to develop this kind of functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the app u talked about.

But what u want can be achieved using fragments. One fragment shows list of hotels. This fragemtns communicates with another fragment using activity such that when an item in that listview is clicked, the information is updated in another fragment.

Here is a link for tutorials about fragments and inter-fragment communication. what u want can be found in tutorials #10 to #20

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo